# Is there a good way to combine like values within the same excel cell?

Tags: excel

I have finally figured out a way to combine much of my data down into much more readable data - but now I can't figure out a good way to eliminate all of the duplicate values within each cell. I will attach images that should explain my issue in more detail.

I used a textjoin when the name of account matches my master list, then use a comma delimiter to stack all values (garment material #) that have the same name. Only problem now, is the excess duplicates in each singular cell. To keep privacy I have changed the numbers and have a smaller version of my actual project which is over 10,000 cells.

[image: screenshot of what the data looks like now]

I would like to combine all of the 270s into 1. All of the 7153s into 1. Etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `UNIQUE` function will get rid of the duplicates. Share your `TEXTJOIN` formula, so it can be amended to cover this (you don't want helper columns). Also, let us know which version of Excel you're using since there are other ways to do it if you don't have Excel 2021 or MS365.

Comment: When I used the Unique function, it didn't combine them for some reason.

=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(FinalNon[Sold-to]=A123,FinalNon[Material '#],""))

Comment: Try `=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(IF(FinalNon[Sold-to]=A123,FinalNon[Material '#],"")))` (the `TRUE` is the default parameter). Possibly, you're after something like `=TEXTJOIN(",",,UNIQUE(IF([Sold-to]=@[Sold-to],[Garment Material '#],"")))` to be used in the same table.

Comment: Dang. So just by adding Unique in front, it fixed my problem. I really appreciate it!